# Pivot Table Standard Deviation Help In Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table like this in Excel:

- Column 'item'
- Column 'brand'
- Column 'score'

As I am not very confident with pivot tables, I was wondering if there was a way of getting the standard deviation for each brand?

e.g. (very basic idea)

`=STDEV(SOMEFUNCTIONTOMAKEARRAY(GETPIVOTDATA(.......)))`

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add an image of the excel spreadsheet with data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you (It's pretty standard and may have been found with a [web search](https://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=see+standard+deviation+in+pivot+table))

1. Select your data
2. In Ribbon **Insert** > **Pivot Table**
3. In the PivotTable Field List drag **brand** to the **Row Labels** area.
4. In the PivotTable Field List drag **score** to the **Values** area.
5. In the Values area select the drop down of the **score** and select **Value Field Settings**
6. Scroll down the list and select either **StdDev** or **StdDevp** and click OK

Comment: Thank you very much; this has been actually very insightful for mr!